# Amazon EMR - subprocess failed with code 1

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I'm running a basic streaming program on EMR, but I keep getting this error. I have replaced my mapper and reducer with a barebones mapper and reducer but this error still stays.

Where is my emr job failing?

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Streaming Command Failed!
```

Comment: Streaming job will throw error like this for all type of errors. First verify your mapper and reducer logic by executing in non mapreduce mode. You can use cat input-file | python mapper.py. If you are using any libraries or any other dependency, that should be there in all the tasktracker/nodemanager nodes.

Comment: Is there a way to extract the error from the nodes? The script seems valid on my test data sets.

Comment: Try executing the same script in another node.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to access the actual application logs in EMR?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a job using hadoop streaming and mrjob: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037300/running-a-job-using-hadoop-streaming-and-mrjob-pipemapred-waitoutputthreads)