# Python Hadoop Streaming Error "ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!" and Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=134

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, subprocess, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to run python script on Hadoop cluster using Hadoop Streaming for sentiment analysis.
The Same script I am running on Local machine which is running Properly and giving output.

to run on local machine I use this command.

```
$ cat /home/MB/analytics/Data/input/* | ./new_mapper.py
```

and to run on hadoop cluster I use below command

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.2.0.jar -mapper "python $PWD/new_mapper.py" -reducer "$PWD/new_reducer.py" -input /user/hduser/Test_04012015_Data/input/* -output /user/hduser/python-mr/out-mr-out
```

The Sample code of my script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys


def main(argv):
##    for line in sys.stdin:
##        print line
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.split(',')
        t_text      = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!|,|!|?|;]',r'',line[7])
        words    = re.findall(r"[\w']+", t_text.rstrip())
        predicted = classifier.classify(feature_select(words))
        i=i+1
        referenceSets[predicted].add(i)
        testSets[predicted].add(i)
        print line[7] +'\t'+predicted

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

The stack trace of Exception is:

```
    15/04/22 12:55:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1429611942931_0010_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
    Error: java.io.IOException: Stream closed at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:434)
    ...

    Exit code: 134
    Exception message: /bin/bash: line 1:  1691 Aborted 
(core dumped) /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera/bin/java
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx525955249
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/yarn/nm/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1429611942931_0010/container_1429611942931_0010_01_000016/tmp
-Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties
-Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1429611942931_0010/container_1429611942931_0010_01_000016 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 
-Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 192.168.0.122 48725 attempt_1429611942931_0010_m_000006_1 16 > /var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1429611942931_0010/container_1429611942931_0010_01_000016/stdout 2> /var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1429611942931_0010/container_1429611942931_0010_01_000016/stderr
    ....

    15/04/22 12:55:47 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!
    Streaming Command Failed!
```

I tried to see logs but in hue it shows me this error.
[image]
Please suggest me, what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to add the file `new_mapper.py` to your job.

Basically, your job tries to run the python script `new_mapper.py`, but this script is missing on the server running your mapper.

You must add this file to your job, using the option `-file <local_path_to_your_file>`.

See documentation and example here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/HadoopStreaming.html#Streaming_Command_Options